# How to select the value of a searched text in PDF using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, text, pymupdf

A PDF contains information as follows:

```
      Name: ABC
Profession: XYZ
   Hobbies: HIJ
```

Using PyMUPDF i am able to search a word in a PDF and highlight it, but i want to highlight the right hand side value of the searched text.
In this example, i want to highlight the value of Name i.e. ABC. because for a different file the Name value may change from ABC to PQR.

Can anyone help on how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I think i myself found a solution to this,

```
import fitz                           #import dependencies
doc  = fitz.open('filename.pdf')      #openPDF 
page = doc[0]

text = "Name"                         #Text intended to search
rl   = page.searchFor(text)           #coordinates of the searched text saved as list (rl-rectangle)

rect = rl[0]+(20,0,20,0)              #to move the rectangle 20 pixels to the right
highlight = page.addHighlightAnnot(rect) # highlight

doc.save("output.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
```

Number of Pixels has to be approximated or set after few trials depending on which direction and how far to move the rectangle.
Hope this helps!